# Some USB devices will automatically reconnect after I unbind it, how to disable it long time?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, udev, sysfs

I'm try to disable my two USB keyboard on my linux system, the one can unbind long time until I unplug then plugin and the number lock light is off during this time. But the other one can not unbind long time, maybe after 5 seconds, it will reconnect again and the number lock light is on during this time, the other lights will flash once, the log shown below:

```
[505545.210490] usb 3-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 47
[505547.687005] usb 3-3.1: new low-speed USB device number 49 using xhci_hcd
[505547.984255] usb 3-3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=6099
[505547.984258] usb 3-3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[505547.984260] usb 3-3.1: Product: Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard
[505548.019948] input: Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.1/3-3.1:1.0/input/input40
[505548.071999] hid-generic 0003:17EF:6099.002A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:03:00.0-3.1/input0
```

Below is my shell command to disable the keyboard:

```
echo "3-3.1"  > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

or

```
echo "0003:17EF:6099.002A" > /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind
```

What is the reason for this difference? Is have a way to disable the second keyboard?

Thank a lot

Comment: I think Unix& Linux stack Exchange I a better place for your question. That site is also part of the Stackoverflow network, and people there know more about the Linux system. You can quickly get to this site by using the network switcher on the top right of the site, and then searching for Unix.

Comment: Ok, I will post the question to Unix& Linux stack Exchange, thank you for your reminder.